# How to integrate zokrates proof into ethereum transactions?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, transactions, zero-knowledge, zokrates

I need some help with applying a Zokrates zero knowledge proof into ethereum transactions

I am using **Goerli** testnet and i have a full node that is fully synced to the ethereum blockchain.

I have written a small proof on Zokrates and it seems to work, according to the inputs i have provided it

I have the **verifier.sol** file as well

Can someone please guide me about the next steps;

specifically that **how can i make am ethereum transaction hide it's ether value** , with the help of the zero knowledge proof ?

Comment: It is not possible to hide the ether value. In order to do that you'll have to modify geth to accept transactions without ether value.

Comment: @Ismael are there any tutorials or documents on how i can do what you suggested ?

Comment: There are several project using zk-snarks for privacy: zksync. Unfortunately they are in research stage or early in their development.